# How change default internet access on a system with more then one interface with internet access

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

I have system with two interface like

eth0 -> 88.198.x.x

eth1 -> 192.168.10.10

I need this server to be accessible from internet throw eth0 but server uses eht1 for it's own internet needs (download, update, etc).

*There is a VPN server behind eth1 to hide my servers location

I tried to remove gateway from eth0 and add one to eth1 but i lost asscess to internet and even ping to eth0
I add getaway to both eth* and then delete default route and then add route to eth1 gateway by

```sh
route del default
route add 192.168.10.10 gw 192.168.10.254
```

but that failed too! how can i fix it?

OS ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hi, your title is misleading, you got one public IP and one private IP. Why the update via your LAN if the server is on the WAN directly ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 you may say that but public or private doesn't matter and my point still stands. Right?

Comment: @yagmoth555 I changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `route add 192.168.10.10 gw 192.168.10.254` tells your system to route only trafic with destination 192.168.10.10 through gateway 192.168.10.254.
It does not seem to be what you want to achieve.

You want to route all trafic (with any destination) through gateway 192.168.10.254 and through dev eth1

Try this one: `route add default gw 192.168.10.254 dev eth1`

You will probably face an other issue when people will try to reach your server through 88.198.x.x. Your server will try to respond back through its default route, eth0, and your local IP 192.168.10.10 is probably "natted" (by your router or your VPN) to a different public IP.
People who will try to reach 88.198.x.x would get packets from a different IP as a response. That will not work.
You must enforce responses to requests coming through eth0 to be sent through eth0. Check this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming